# Where to look for "standard" ODE solutions?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, online-resources

I remember one day having stumbled upon a nice online resource where one could look for solutions to very general ODEs (or at least the literature names thereof), but unfortunately I forgot its location... So, where can one go looking to e.g. figure out that

$$\frac{d}{dr}\left[(1-r^2)\frac{d}{dr}f(r)\right] + l(l+1)f(r) = 0$$

is the [Legendre differential equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_polynomial), especially if one doesn't know about this particular representation?

Comment: Not online (except partially on Google Books), but good: Zwillinger's *Handbook of Differential Equations*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also try http://eqworld.ipmnet.ru
For example for your request: http://eqworld.ipmnet.ru/en/solutions/ode/ode0223.pdf

Comment: I'm almost certain that's the very resource I meant, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Wolfram MathWorld has a long list of common ODEs with solutions:
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/OrdinaryDifferentialEquation.html

Comment: Ah, good old wolfram. Of course, [alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com) might be worth a shot as well